# What type does C++ expect for array subscripts?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, standards, subscript-operator

In C, array subscription: `a[b]` is merely the syntactic sugar equivalent of dereferencing after pointer arithmetic: `*(a+b)` (as explained, say, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18393343/1593077)).

How is array subscription interpreted in C++, for base types? (Not for classes, for which we have overload semantics)? And, more specifically, what type does C++ expect to appear as the subscript? Is it a `ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: C++ does the same thing C does for base types.

Comment: I think the article you link to explains it well. For basic types, `a[b]` is valid if and only if `*(a + b)` is. So the valid types for `b` depend on the type of `a`, but basically any integer type is fine if `a` is a pointer-to-object type, or any pointer-to-object type if `a` is an integer type. What's the question, are you just asking for confirmation that answer is correct when it says, "C++ inherited this definition from C"?

Comment: I think it does the same thing for all data types...I can't think of a data type treated differently by c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is exactly the same as C in this respect. C++11 §5.2.1:

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by deﬁnition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

Answer (score 7):

> How is array subscription interpreted in C++,

In *C++* `E1[E2]` is *identical* to `*((E1)+(E2))`

> what type does C++ expect to appear as the subscript?

*C++* expects a *unscoped enumeration or integral type* both items are covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.2.1` *Subscripting* paragraph *1* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “pointer to T” and the **other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type**. The result is an lvalue of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.<sup>62</sup> The **expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))** [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. —end note ]

As James points out, the wording *One of the expressions shall have* allows the *pointer* and *subscript* to be interchanged, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ;

    std::cout << arr[2] << ":" << 2[arr] << std::endl ;
}
```

Using the alternative syntax `2[arr]` is not recommended, most people won't know what this is doing it makes the code less readable and hence less maintainable.

which is similar to the relevant section in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) `6.5.2.1` *Array subscripting* paragraph *2* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is **that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))**. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) **and E2 is an integer**, E1[E2] designates the E2-th
>   element of E1 (counting from zero).

Comment: Note that it is "one of the expressions" which has an integral type.  Something like `int * array; [10]array` is perfectly legal (and perfectly horrible).

Comment: @JamesKanze fair point, I should probably note that, it is not really obvious.

Comment: @JamesKanze actually you mean `10[array]` the grammar does not allow for `[10]array`.

Comment: Yes.  (It's not something I use everyday:-))  And since you mention it now, _do_ mention that it is not at all recommended.

Comment: @JamesKanze amended and I had to try it out myself as well.